# Sharepoint App shows error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I started a new project and edited the Default.aspx file of my Client Web Part and when trying to build it and it comes up with an error. I am using SharePoint 2013 being hosted on Office 365, and I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. The error does not give me any information though on how to solve it below is my code:

This is my updated code:

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hostweburl;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
                var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

                var dclink = document.createElement("link");
                dclink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                dclink.setAttribute("href", scriptbase + "defaultcss.ashx");

                var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
                head[0].appendChild(dclink);
            });

            function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetreive) {
                var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
                var strParams = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetreive)
                        return singleParam[1];
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <h1 class="ms-core-pageTitle">Your First SharePoint Application</h1>
            <h1 class="ms-accentText">Put your app UI here.</h1>
            <div>
                <h2 class="ms-webpart-titleText">Use the SharePoint CSS</h2>
                <a class="ms-commandLink" href="#">links</a>
                <br />
                You can use the SharePoint CSS in your app by referencing it in your pages
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Elements.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ClientWebPart Name="MyAppPart" Title="MyAppPart Title" Description="MyAppPart Description" DefaultWidth="300" DefaultHeight="200">

    <!-- Content element identifies the location of the page that will render inside the client web part
         Properties are referenced on the query string using the pattern _propertyName_
         Example: Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/ClientWebPart1.aspx?Property1=_property1_" -->
    <Content Type="html" Src="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}" />

    <!-- Define properties in the Properties element.
         Remember to put Property Name on the Src attribute of the Content element above. -->
    <Properties>
    </Properties>

  </ClientWebPart>
</Elements>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm still very new to SP 2013

**EDIT**

Above is the updated code. It is the Default.aspx file from the Client web part that the tutorial I'm doing has me do. When I build it I get the following error displayed in the browser:

[image]

Comment: Is this a Provider-hosted app or a SharePoint-hosted app?

Comment: Definitely provider hosted if he has `Default.aspx.cs`! You should include the contents of the error or the behavior it generates, even if it doesn't make sense to you it will help others troubleshoot your problem rather than having to try and recreate your problem in their own environment. You're also not showing the code behind, so without the code or the error it's producing this will be a tough problem to solve!

Comment: @John-M Sorry I updated the question, and the app is a SharePoint hosted app